# Validation at property level

Tags: c#, validation, properties, mvvmcross

I'm trying to do a simple validation within the properties which in `PCL` project.

The reason why I do this validation here, *that I can use it for other platform like Android and IOS.*

Below is my code I have tried so far:

```
private string _mobileNumber;
        public string MobileNumber
        {
            get { return _mobileNumber; }
            set { _mobileNumber = MobileNumberValidation(value); RaisePropertyChanged(() => MobileNumber); }
        }
```

The validation method:

```
public string MobileNumberValidation(string theMobileNumber)
        {         
            Regex regexExpression = new Regex(@"^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[89]\d{9}$");
            regexExpression.IsMatch(theMobileNumber);
            return "Heck its works ";
        }
```

Correct me if my approach is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any validation code here

Comment: Well if you really want to do it that way, your `MobileNumberValidation` method should return true/false. And in your property setter, only update value & raise `propertychanged` when true is returned

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private string _mobileNumber;

public string MobileNumber
{
   get { return _mobileNumber; }
   set 
   { 
      if (!MobileNumberValidation(value))
         throw new Exception("Invalid mobile number");

      _mobileNumber = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => MobileNumber);
   }
}

private bool MobileNumberValidation(string theMobileNumber)
{         
   Regex regexExpression = new Regex(@"^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[89]\d{9}$");
   return regexExpression.IsMatch(theMobileNumber);
}
```